# Require.js in Node

Tags: node.js, requirejs

How to use require.js in node.js?

why the following code does not work?

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['foo'],
function (foo) {
    console.log(foo);
});
```

I have tried various things, including using requirejs(['./foo'].  I'm unable to get anything to work.

I have a file foo.js in the same directory as the main file (the one with the above code).  I run the main file with node and foo is undefined.  From the examples given on requirejs.org it looks like I am doing it right, but I am certain I am misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your exact code, with a fresh install of requirejs, and a very mininal 'foo' module and it worked fine. I would imagine the problem is in the foo module itself.

Here is what I used

```
define(function(){
    return 'test';
});
```

Have you got the module syntax wrong?

Comment: Thank you!  I did not write the module I was trying to load, and I didn't even think that the problem was in the module.  I am a little unsure how I am supposed to use the module, but now I know what I was doing wrong.

If you know how I am supposed to use the module, it's in the format:
var x = new function() {
this. y = new function(){};
}

I want to be able to use the function y.  I thought that what I was doing would allow me to go foo.y().

Comment: define(function(){
        return { y: new function() { } }
    });